# What trade is best to fix the crack in my livingroom ceiling?

Tags: drywall, ceiling

We have now noticed a crack running along the length of the living room ceiling.
Looking to see who I need to come and look and fix it for me, so what trade, ie builder or joiner?

[image: Long crack in ceiling]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Are your ceilings plaster or drywall (sheetrock)?  It takes a bit more skill to do a good repair job to a plaster wall than to a drywall ceiling, IMO.

Comment: What's above that ceiling?  Another floor, or attic?  Sometimes drywall cracks in the ceiling can be a sign that there's a roof leak.  It's hard to tell from that photo, but look carefully for any signs of water damage.

Comment: @SteveSh It sure looks like a normal drywall tape joint.  Plaster walls don't have joints like that.

Comment: @TylerH The crack is easy to fill (assuming you can get to it) but doing a nice job of drywall is quite another matter.  I'm fairly DIY around the house--but anything where looks matter I'll hire out.

Comment: @TylerH, spackle won't fix this. It's obviously a result of seasonal movement, and such a repair will last about five minutes.

Comment: @isherwood *shrug* I don't think we can reasonably say it's "obviously" *anything*, without either seeing it ourselves or a fair amount more information from OP (how long has the crack been there, what does it look like from above, was there a wall there previously, did the crack appear suddenly or over weeks/months/years, etc).

Comment: I've seen that exact things many times over my professional and homeowner life. To me it's obvious. That's not a quick fix. It's a re-tape at the very minimum.

Answer (score 10):

*From comments:* These are all UK terms. If someone from the US would be kind enough to edit in appropriate transpondian translations, that would be more than welcome. I've added a table at the end. [Now almost complete].

You need a general builder who also does plasterwork & joinery.

First task isn't to fix it but to figure out why it's slumping. I doubt it's water damage, as the scrim joints would usually survive that to a mild degree without cracking. You'd also probably see slight discolouration.

That the joint has cracked not only along the join but also at the scrim edges makes me think the joist has moved.
You need to figure out why that happened.

I'm also worried by the fact that you can not only see a nail, which implies the plaster skim was barely adequate thickness, but also that it appears to have pulled back under the surface, which hints at a fair bit of tension in the joint. It could have been over-hit at install, but I'd expect to see a correspondingly clumsy hammer mark round it.

[image]

That it's at what appears to be either a chimney breast edge or possibly a removed wall needs further investigation, as to what's above.

*Translations, UK to US*

| UK | US |
| --- | --- |
| general builder | contractor/subcontractor |
| joinery | trim |
| joist | joist |
| plasterboard | drywall |
| plaster | drywall mud/joint compound |
| skim | spackle? |
| scrim | drywall tape |

In the UK, 'plaster' is a generic term for anything you put on an indoor wall or ceiling, then smooth flat; whether it's onto brick, block, board, lathes, etc. There are specific sub-terms, bonding, skim etc, but the builder/contractor would deal with the specifics.

My own plasterwork knowledge comes not from ever doing this myself, but my using the services of my [now ex-]father-in-law, who was a professional plasterer [now retired]. I never once saw him use a screw for plasterboard, though research prompted by comments shows this has become far more common in recent years, even in the UK.

Comment: Are you seriously telling me you nail drywall in the US rather than using plasterboard screws?

Comment: This answer is applicable in the UK, but in NA you won't find a "general builder" anywhere, nor will most contractors know what you mean when you say "plasterwork" - they'll probably assume plaster lath, at best, or maybe foundation work or parging, because if it was just a drywall job you'd simply say so.  Even "joinery" would be interpreted to mean woodworking, specifically fine or finish carpentry.  Where OP is in the world will matter when it comes to finding the right serviceperson for the job.

Comment: @J… they might have different names but it's still the same job. Rather than say what you *won't* find, how about translating the terminology into what you *will* find in the US, as that would help anybody visiting this question. BTW, we don't actually know where this is as yet.

Comment: @crobar Older homes use nails, sure, and not just in the US, but everywhere in the world that has this kind of drywall/plasterboard ceiling (you may be surprised at how strong a ring shank nail is if you've never tried to pull one out after ~50 years), but this could easily be a screw, too. Hard to tell since the material over it could be hiding the bit indentation in the head. Keep in mind the "drywall screw" wasn't invented until 1950.

Comment: @Tetsujin Builder = contractor.  OP would look for a drywall contractor in NA.  It's unlikely the trim would need to be touched, but even if so it's not usually so specific that you would ask for a drywall contractor who *also does trim* (ie: joinery) - I'd be shocked if you could find me a residential drywall contractor who couldn't also do a bit of trim work.

Answer (score 0):

Ceilings that are drywalled, which this one obviously is (because of the tape coming unattached) should have been glued with liquid nail and fastened with screws.
Especially if there is an upstairs. Vibrations from walking will slowly cause a crack if drywall is not properly installed. Nonetheless any experienced painter or drywaller can

1. cut the tape loose
2. add screws along both sides the seam and on studs 16" off both sides of the seam (use stud finder)
3. use new fiberglass mesh tape over seam where tape was removed
4. durabond instead of drywall mud for first coat skim
5. finally plus 3 drywall finish mud skim
6. prime with pva primer
7. paint entire ceiling

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with the process described by your answer, it doesn't actually answer the question asked. The OP doesn't seem to be interested in a DIY solution, but is asking what trade he should hire to do the fix for him. If you'd care to [edit] your answer to address that question, I'm sure it will be more useful.

Comment: I've never once in decades of home construction and remodeling seen glued drywall.