# Crack in ceilling

Tags: ceiling, crack

I living in a townhome in the Northeast area, and now I see a crack line in my ceiling. Above the ceiling is the attic.

Is this a minor problem just the paint is cracking, or I need to fix the dry wall?

[image]

Comment: Someone can correct me but it sort of looks like it's the tape on the drywall joint.

Comment: Can you get into the attic and look at the back of this?

Comment: Lots of good information in a [recent post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/239556/what-trade-is-best-to-fix-the-crack-in-my-livingroom-ceiling). There are other similar posts to be found with a search.

Comment: You need to repair it anyway, so why not use a utility knife cut it open to exam what is beneath.

Comment: @r13, it would take a heck of a hole to see what's inside from below to any useful extent, possibly messing up vapor barrier and insulation. That's not good advice. I'd look from above.

Comment: Vapor barrier and insulation on the surface of the ceiling? If it is made of drywall board, cut the paper open then the crack beneath may tell the story or reveal it is just the drywall joint.

Comment: Unlike the question isherwood linked, this one shows the very vaguest, slightest hints there may be damp involved. Most of the joint looks like it's bent, not broken. Definitely get above it & see what's going on. [btw, it's nigh-on impossible to tell if it's damp from a photo unless it's properly damp, so I'm completely guessing. In the linked question I tried to take a good photo of one I know to have been caused by damp, but I couldn't get any shot that showed the signs in a way you could see in the pic.].